# Binding Button IsEnabled to ComboBox Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know this can be done in a converter, but I'd like to disable a button based on a particular item selected in a ComboBox, using only XAML.

The following below works, using the Visibility property. How come if I try to use IsEnabled it does not work? Is there something I'm missing? If that's the way it is, if someone could explain why, that would be great. Should I just always use converters?

```
<ComboBox Name="WidthTypeComboBox" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WidthType}}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding WidthTypeSelected}" />
```

Works:

```
<Button Content="Map Channels" Command="{Binding ShowChannelAction}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, 
                    ElementName=WidthTypeComboBox}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Does not work:

```
<Button Content="Map Channels" Command="{Binding ShowChannelAction}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, 
                    ElementName=WidthTypeComboBox}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Visibility in XAML is not the same as Boolean.. That's why we have converters bool -> visibility and visiblity -> bool ;)

Comment: There's no shame in using an IValueConverter. Artificial constraints like "I'll only use XAML" are not always the best idea.

Comment: @jan.h, I agree. I just usually try to use XAML and then a converter if the XAML will be too complex or not very readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually not sure how the first one is working. It depends on what you've set for the properties on your button. Usually you need a default setter in the style and to remove any IsEnabled value set locally on the button:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, 
            ElementName=WidthTypeComboBox}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It comes down to the precedence of where the property value is set. For example, property values set locally override style setter/triggers. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) explains dependency property precendence with some examples.

Comment: Using the default setter made it work. Thanks for the explanation. The article also helped a lot.